# C Vector initialization and use

Tags: c++, vector

I'm writing my first c program to be run on a raspberry pi which uses pigpio to create waves and an Adafruit_1015 ADC to capture data from a receiver when a pigpio callback is triggered.  The code is working fine and I can output the ADC data to the screen.  Now what I need to do is capture those data readings into a vector so that I can average it and then capture the standard deviation of the total readings, which may be anywhere from 100 to 1000 elements in total.

I have the following applicable lines before the main function:

```
#include <vector>
#define datavector
std::vector <int16_t> datavector;`
```

Then within the pigpio callback (named edges) to add data to the vector, I am using

```
`std::vector<datavector>.push_back(adc2);`
```

The adc2 is the data read from channel 2 of the ADC of a type int16_t.

The problem I am having is that when I try to compile (gcc) I get the following error message:

```
main.cpp:46:6: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
std::vector <int16_t> datavector;
  ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void edges(int, int, uint32_t)’:
main.cpp:148:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
datavector.push_back(adc2);
```

It seems that I've done everything correctly, but clearly something is wrong.  Can someone point me in the right direction on this implementation of a vector?

EDIT:
If I remove the #define datavector as recommended by Jean, I get many more compiler errors that read as follows:

```
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o: In function `std::_Vector_base<short, std::allocator<short> >::~_Vector_base()':
main.cpp: (.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIsSaIsEED2Ev[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIsSaIsEED5Ev]+0x64): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIsSaIsEED2Ev[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIsSaIsEED5Ev]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o: In function `std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<short*, std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> > >, short const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs[_ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs]+0x290): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs[_ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs]+0x294): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs[_ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs]+0x2a0): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs[_ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs]+0x308): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs[_ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPsS1_EERKs]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o: In function `std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >::_M_check_len(unsigned int, char const*) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIsSaIsEE12_M_check_lenEjPKc[_ZNKSt6vectorIsSaIsEE12_M_check_lenEjPKc]+0x54): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<short>::deallocate(short*, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIsE10deallocateEPsj[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIsE10deallocateEPsj]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<short>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIsE8allocateEjPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIsE8allocateEjPKv]+0x40): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIsE8allocateEjPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIsE8allocateEjPKv]+0x50): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o: In function `std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >::~vector()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEED2Ev[_ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEED5Ev]+0x60): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccMOBzge.o:(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEED2Ev[_ZNSt6vectorIsSaIsEED5Ev]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I'm fairly certain that's not the right answer.

Comment: `#define datavector` removes the `datavector` token. Don't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define datavector
std::vector <int16_t> datavector;
```

is seen (after pre-processing) as

```
std::vector <int16_t>;
```

hence the error(s) you're experiencing (also explains the error there:  `datavector.push_back(adc2);`). Just remove the `#define` line, which is useless.

Also note that this isn't a C program but a C++ program, hence you have to build it with `g++` (which explains the linker errors of your edit)

Comment: Hi Jean I don't think that's the whole solution.  I've edited my question to include the errors that get generated after removing the #define statement.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Am I using the wrong compiler?  When I tried g++ instead of gcc I get no erros.

Comment: those are not compiler errors, those are linker errors, and yes, it's C++, not C (I even edited your question tag). There's a difference!!

Comment: Thanks Jean.  I think I'm on the right track now.  Once I use your recommendation to remove the #define and compile with g++, compiler errors go away and it seems to work fine.  Thanks for the help!